# Re-Usable Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have 3 tables with the exact same DDL (I know that is a horrid set-up), but each one has a different values for a field.  I am hoping to be able to have a way to write ONE query for all 3 selects as opposed to having to use 3 different select queries.  Here is sample DDL and the individual queries, could this be merged into 1 query?

```
Create Table InfoForJane
(
  genid int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
  ,name varchar(500)
  ,numofdays varchar(100)
)
Create Table InfoForJoe
(
  genid int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
  ,name varchar(500)
  ,numofdays varchar(100)
)
Create Table InfoForJessie
(
  genid int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
  ,name varchar(500)
  ,numofdays varchar(100)
)
```

And here are the queries that I would ideally like merged into one

```
Select 
genid
,name
,case
  when numofdays NOT IN ('1-3','4-6','7-9') then '1-3'
  else numofdays
end As [NumofDays]
from rashapa.munich.dbo.InfoForJane

Select
genid
,name
,case
  when numofdays NOT IN ('1-5','6-10','11-14') then '1-5'
  else numofdays
end As [NumofDays]
from rashapa.munich.dbo.InfoForJoe

Select 
genid
,name
,case
  when numofdays NOT IN ('1-2','3-8','8-12') then '1-2'
  else numofdays
end As [NumofDays]
from rashapa.munich.dbo.InfoForJessie
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for the "UNION ALL" operator.  See the example below.  If you are going to be using this a lot, you could even turn it into a view and then query the view.  I've added a column "SourceTable" but that is my personal preference when doing things like this, your needs may vary and it may be superfluous for your environment.

```
SELECT  genid
      , name
      , SourceTable = 'InfoForJane'
      , CASE WHEN numofdays NOT IN ( '1-3', '4-6', '7-9' ) THEN '1-3'
             ELSE numofdays
        END AS [NumofDays]
FROM    rashapa.munich.dbo.InfoForJane
UNION ALL
SELECT  genid
      , name
      , SourceTable = 'InfoForJoe'
      , CASE WHEN numofdays NOT IN ( '1-5', '6-10', '11-14' ) THEN '1-5'
             ELSE numofdays
        END AS [NumofDays]
FROM    rashapa.munich.dbo.InfoForJoe
UNION ALL
SELECT  genid
      , name
      , SourceTable = 'InfoForJessie'
      , CASE WHEN numofdays NOT IN ( '1-2', '3-8', '8-12' ) THEN '1-2'
             ELSE numofdays
        END AS [NumofDays]
FROM    rashapa.munich.dbo.InfoForJessie;
```

Answer (score 3):

UNION ALL should do it. Like this:

```
Select 
    genid
    ,name
    ,case
      when numofdays NOT IN ('1-3','4-6','7-9') then '1-3'
      else numofdays
    end As [NumofDays]
    from rashapa.munich.dbo.InfoForJane

    UNION ALL

    Select
    genid
    ,name
    ,case
      when numofdays NOT IN ('1-5','6-10','11-14') then '1-5'
      else numofdays
    end As [NumofDays]
    from rashapa.munich.dbo.InfoForJoe

    UNION ALL

    Select 
    genid
    ,name
    ,case
      when numofdays NOT IN ('1-2','3-8','8-12') then '1-2'
      else numofdays
    end As [NumofDays]
    from rashapa.munich.dbo.InfoForJessie
```

Or build a view:

```
CREATE VIEW vwMergedQueries AS

    Select 
        genid
        ,name
        ,case
          when numofdays NOT IN ('1-3','4-6','7-9') then '1-3'
          else numofdays
        end As [NumofDays]
        from rashapa.munich.dbo.InfoForJane

        UNION ALL

        Select
        genid
        ,name
        ,case
          when numofdays NOT IN ('1-5','6-10','11-14') then '1-5'
          else numofdays
        end As [NumofDays]
        from rashapa.munich.dbo.InfoForJoe

        UNION ALL

        Select 
        genid
        ,name
        ,case
          when numofdays NOT IN ('1-2','3-8','8-12') then '1-2'
          else numofdays
        end As [NumofDays]
        from rashapa.munich.dbo.InfoForJessie
```

Then you can query the view as a single entity:

```
SELECT * FROM vwMergedQueries
```